# Mask <img/> without changing height or positioning

Tags: html, css, crop, centering

I have a page [here](http://iamwasserman.com/Portfolio) with a vertically and horizontally centered image.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

#background {
  z-index: -1000;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#background-img {
  width: calc(100% + 200px);
  height: calc(100% + 200px);
  margin-left: -100px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  filter: blur(50px);
}

#body-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#display {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#display-img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 33px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: .5;
/*  height: 50px;*/
}


#display-img-placeholder {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 33px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
/*
  width: 930px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 66px);
  margin: 0 auto;
*/
  filter: contrast(1.5);
/*  position: relative;*/
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

#display-img-placeholder img {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

#display-img img {
  width: 100%;
}

#img-container {
  max-width: calc(100% - 66px);
/*
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 33px;
*/
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 930px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 66px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
    <div id="background">
      <img id="background-img" src="http://iamwasserman.com/Portfolio/hoh.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="body-container">
      <div id="display">
        <div id="img-container">
          <div id="display-img-placeholder">
            <img src="http://iamwasserman.com/Portfolio/hoh.jpg">
          </div>
          <div id="display-img">
            <img src="http://iamwasserman.com/Portfolio/hoh.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
        <h3 id="time-stamp"></h3>
        <div id="dots">
          <div class="dot"></div>
          <div class="dot"></div>
          <div class="dot"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I need a way to crop off the bottom 15% of the image that won't affect the positioning (so it has to stay the same size but make the bottom section transparent). I've tried putting a container `<div>` around it and changing the height but then it changes the image's vertical position. Ideas on how to do this?

s.a. [1](http://iamwasserman.com/Portfolio) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgNDR.jpg)

Comment: post your html and css codes

Comment: You could add a div that overlaps the bottom of this image, and set the width of the image to 100% of the container div. This will give the appearance that the bottom of the image is removed, when its just sitting behind the div.

Comment: @MehdiKarimi it's all at that link

Comment: would be helpful still to have the code in the question as I guess SO stays for longer than this demo-site ;) – also consider adding your constrains that keep you from doing things *and* also say why.

Comment: You are required to post your markup here, not a third party site that can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one in the future. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @vv01f It's a requirement and why this question will eventually be closed.

Answer (score 0):

is that to your liking?

```css
#wrap{/* to demonstrate the image on top is partially transparent */
  background-color: rgba(128,128,255,128);
}
#bg {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgNDR.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-position: -288px, -115px;
/* 1437x768 */
  width: 862px;
  height: 538px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 115px 288px ;
}
#clip {
/* this is deprecated
  clip: rect( 115px, 288px,  115px, 288px );
*/
/* this works */
clip-path:  inset( 115px 288px  115px 288px );
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<!--
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgNDR.jpg" />

<div id="bg">
</div>
-->

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgNDR.jpg" id="clip"/>

</div>
```

### background position

basically this makes it possible to have your image the original size
but position the linked image a selfcalculated measure off the start.

I first calculated -15% for top and then adjusted the left offset. later width my 2x the difference between original size and offsets.

manual calculation of course may be automated with javascript.

### clip

is old but works somehow with css only; you can even do [more than just rectangle](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/)

Comment: Unfortunately there are a lot of other things going on in my html that don't allow this to work. The image also does not have a defined size.

Comment: well, then you better calculate that stuff on-the-fly with javascript; but principle can be the same; still, maybe it is possible relatively with css only as well

Comment: found anaother way with `clip-path`; to achieve the blur, I guess you need to have the image two times on top of each other